# How do I work with background in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

In my app, I want to create some sort of parallax effect, just like this, where the content overlap the background : [video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yfGol.jpg)
This is what I made in Figma: [figma prototype](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNzxL.jpg)
And this is what I currently have : [current prototype](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZZPs.jpg)

How do I allow the content to go over the picture and how am I supposed to only have the bottom of the picture for the background ? (I don't want to cut it since it could mess on other devices)

Here is my code :

```
import React from 'react'
import {ImageBackground,View, ScrollView, Text, StyleSheet, Dimensions} from 'react-native'
import {generalStyles} from '@gym-app/styles/general'

export default function MuscleScreen() {

    const Image = require('../assets/muscles/abs.jpg')
    return (
        <ScrollView>
            <ImageBackground source={Image} style={styles.background}>
                <View style={[generalStyles.container, styles.overlap]}>
                    <Text style={generalStyles.title}>Abdominaux</Text>
                </View>
            </ImageBackground>
        </ScrollView>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    background: {
        width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
        height: (Dimensions.get('window').width / 16 * 9),
        resizeMode: 'cover'
    },
    overlap: {
        position: 'absolute',
        top: (Dimensions.get('window').width / 16 * 9),
        width: Dimensions.get('window').width
    }

})
```

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your ImageBackground behind the ScrollView, e.g.

```
<View>
    <ImageBackground />
    <ScrollView />
<View>
```

1. Give ScrollView absolute position taking entire screen
2. As a first item in ScrollView, add blank space (empty View) with height of a
   window you want for the picture
3. Capture current scroll position of
   ScrollView with [Animated.event](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/animated#event)
4. [Interpolate](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/animations#interpolation) that value so that it scrolls up slightly slower than ScrollView and apply it as `transform translateY` of your ImageBackground